# Wants to install BI Publisher standalone

Tags: bi-publisher

My question is about to install BI Publisher on my machine.

> I want BI Publisher as standalone . I do not want it as plugin in Microsoft word.

Thanks
Vivek shokeen

Answer (score 0):

The word addon is optional, it is not required to use BIP. Once you have BIP server running, you can create reports directly from data sources, using the New Report wizard. The Word Addon is required to create report templates, which cannot be achieved using the wizard.

Download the BIP Windows server installable from eDelivery for standalone BIP server.